# Migration Failed ASP.Net API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have problem when I'm trying to update the database.
I'm making web-api with asp.net.

I just added new migration and works perfectly. Then updated my database with update-database command. Then I change some codes. When I add new migration it said:

```
Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: 
[201705310248355_changeProduct, 201706191007322_ModifyModel, 201707170631209_changeProductModel, 201707170652556_EditProductModelLagi, 201707180312064_AddStorageIdOnInventory, 201707190243206_ChangeRepository, 201708091124374_EditInventory, 201803130702299_testBoom]. 

Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.
```

but last time I updated the database it works perfectly

```
PM> update-database -target testboom -startupprojectname ShopDiaryProject.EF -force
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is already at version 201803130702299_testBoom.
```

Soo, I tried to add-migration with -force parameter.
It works!

BUT,

I update the database again, the migration content likes start from beginning and can't add tables.
Here are my migration:

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Categories",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(maxLength: 200),
                    Description = c.String(maxLength: 200),
                    UserId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    CreatedDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    ModifiedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    DeletedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    CreatedUserId = c.String(),
                    ModifiedUserId = c.String(),
                    DeletedUserID = c.String(),
                    IsDeleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    User_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.User_Id)
            .Index(t => t.User_Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Products",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(maxLength: 250),
                    BarcodeId = c.String(maxLength: 250),
                    CategoryId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    CreatedDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    ModifiedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    DeletedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    CreatedUserId = c.String(),
                    ModifiedUserId = c.String(),
                    DeletedUserID = c.String(),
                    IsDeleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.CategoryId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.CategoryId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Shopitems",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Quantity = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    price = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    ProductId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    ShoplistId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    CreatedDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    ModifiedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    DeletedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    CreatedUserId = c.String(),
                    ModifiedUserId = c.String(),
                    DeletedUserID = c.String(),
                    IsDeleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                })
```

and it said There is already an object named 'Categories' in the database.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure Wishlists table exists?

Comment: forget it, I reverted the migration to previous version. then add new migration and works perfectly.

Thanks btw :)